# Is this .htaccess good?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've this .htaccess file that move all the request to index.php?request=(URI) that elaborates them, except for URI that starts with `-file/` that means we are trying to access a public file. Inside the system/root/ there's only the public index.php file that manage the request so that final users cannot see any system/ file. And application/public/ contains only CSS, images, javascript and public stuff.

1. Is this safe?

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule -file/(.*) application/public/$1 [L]

   # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ system/root/index.php?request=$1 [NC,L]
   ```
2. It works, but does this code has something more that should be deleted or something that miss that should be added?
3. The commented line has any sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
RewriteRule ^-file/(.*) application/public/$1 [L]
```

Otherwise, it would match something like

```
http://domain.com/controller/method/any-file/
```

Unless you know that you'll never use `-file` in any of your `system/root` requests.

Comment: Correct, ^ means the request starts with the expression that follows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put every output through index.php, you should put the other files outside of the document root. If you do that, you only need the .htaccess to redirect a request to index.php, but you will not have the risk of exposing files you don't want to expose.

That said, it seems okay to me.

Comment: Every file is outside the system/root/ Important files are in folders such as system/core/ or system/classes/ or other. Inside system/root/ there's only the file that should be accessed. Also if I'd do a redirect request it wouldn't automatically send the URI to $_GET['request']. Isn't it?